# Quasar framework- Built app looking for an IP address in mobile

Tags: cordova, quasar-framework

I am building a quasar-framework app.

Running the "quasar dev -m cordova -T android -t mat" command, with mobile connected to the computer works correctly (picks my device's IP as external IP)..

However, when I install the 'apk' generated by above command in mobile, it looks for the same external IP in mobile and says 'cannot connect to 192...:/index.html'

When I use 'build for production' command (quasar build -m cordova -T android -t mat) and try to copy the apk generated, the device says 'App cannot be installed'.

How do I install the apk generated by dev /build commands in the device?

TIA

Comment: The exact error, when not connected to Internet, is:
The webpage at http://192…:8080/index.html could not be loaded because:
net: ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

When connected to Internet, it says:
The connection to the server was unsuccessful (http://…:8080/index.html)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Same as Jason, did you find a solution ? Im receiving the same message, App cannot be installed

Answer (score 1):

I installed the latest version of the JDK and it solved the issue for me.